# Google Vis: Invalid data table format: must have 3 or 4 data columns

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I would like to visualize two ore more timesheets on the same timeline. I have added twice these as cols: **Label, Start_time, end_time** and I have also added rows as exact variables. After that I have got the following error message in output:

`Invalid data table format: must have 3 or 4 data columns.`

**UPDATE**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFZYU.png

Comment: What do you mean with timesheets? If you want to have multiple date axis, not sure if that is possible but if you mean to have several entries in the timeline, you need to add them as new rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see. To have several timesheets in the same row, you need to use 4 columns: the first one with the name of the column, the second one with the name of the timesheet, the third one with start_time and fourth one with end_time. Here is an example taking into account your image, though you need to change the dates:

```
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Magnolia Room',          'CSS Fundamentals', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Magnolia Room',          'Intro Javascript',        new Date(1797, 2, 3),  new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Magnolia Room',          'Advanced Javascript',  new Date(1801, 2, 3),  new Date(1809, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Gladiolus Room',     'Intermediate Perl',        new Date(1789, 3, 20), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Gladiolus Room',     'Advanced Perl',  new Date(1797, 2, 3),  new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Gladiolus Room',     'Applied Perl',        new Date(1801, 2, 3),  new Date(1805, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Petunia Room',     'Google Charts',    new Date(1805, 2, 3),  new Date(1812, 3, 19)],
    [ 'Petunia Room', 'Closure',          new Date(1789, 8, 25), new Date(1790, 2, 21)],
    [ 'Petunia Room', 'App Engine',  new Date(1790, 2, 21), new Date(1793, 11, 30)]
    ]);
```

Took this from this example: [Google TimeLine Advanced Example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#AdvancedExample)